# Background music for a web page game

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am making a game in an HTML web page. How would I add music to this game?

Comment: SO needs a new reason to close: "saving civilization".

Comment: It's tacky.  A better solution is to put a real music player somewhere on the screen.  You can make it auto-play if you really must.

Comment: Its for a game. I know, I hate website background music too.

Comment: To everyone thinking this should *never* be allowed: **Google did [background music](http://www.google.com/pacman/) recently** and appropriately.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because 1. it's for a game, not **just a website**. and 2. The question that this links to now is a sucky question with no answers.

Comment: To clarify Earlz: background music for a game has different considerations from bg music for a static website.  That is why this isn't a dupe.

Comment: Apart from the horrors of background music (is there some nomusic plugin for Firefox?), I fail to see how web markup is programming related.

Comment: @starblue: Writing games using javascript is programming related. Programmaticly controlling background music used in a game (e.g. change it between levels or based on score) is programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<embed src="bgsound.mp3" autostart="true">
```

http://www.htmlf1.com/tutorial/html-background-music.html

Comment: Is there anyway for it to play without showing a Music Player? This is for a game. I need it to just play.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart=false loop=false>
```

You may use javascript also

```
function func1() { 
document.all.sound.src = "sound.wav"
} 
window.onload=func1;
```

Comment: Is there anyway for it to play without showing a Music Player? This is for a game. I need it to just play.

Comment: <embed src="nice music tone.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true">

Comment: You may use javascript also

function func1() { 
 document.all.sound.src = "sound.wav"
} 
window.onload=func1;

Comment: Is there any code that can be run on Canvas or HTML5 audio Tag? This is for a Mobile Phone game.